# Does a graphic card needed in led 32 inches normal TV using as monitor

Tags: display, external-display, 4k-resolution, led

I wanna change my lg 32 inches led TV into a monitor so this screen is much larger than normal monitor so plz suggest me if I have to add some graphics card into this or their is no need to add graphics card

Comment: add graphics card to what? A PC?What make and model?

Answer (score 1):

The size of the monitor doesn't have anything to do whether you need a graphics adapter or not.

What does matter is the inputs on the back of the TV and the outpus that are on the back of your PC or laptop dock--and what you want to do exactly.

For example -- if your TV has an HDMI input, and your computer/laptop dock doesn't, then you need either:

- a graphics card installed with an HDMI output.

  - This option adds an additional output and lets you use 2 or more monitors at once.
  - If you are using a laptop with something like a USB-C dock, this is not an option.  You might look into getting another dock with more outputs though.
- check your favorite search for "HDMI-to-X dongle" - X being the output on the back of your PC or existing graphics card.

  - This option lets you use an existing output already on the back of your PC or laptop dock.
  - You might run into problems with certain types of input/output combinations, but if your TV is newer and you are trying to get a DisplayPort or HDMI on both sides working, you'll probably not have too much trouble.

Comment: Snap! you finished your answer 12s before I finished mine!  ;-)

Comment: I think you have inputs and outputs mixed. Otherwise a good answer!

Comment: Not enough caffeine.  Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Modern TVs can be used as monitors if they have a signal connection standard in common with a computer's existing video adapter

For example, a TV with an HDMI input connector can be connected to a computer that has an HDMI output connector.

Some TVs and some older computers will have a VGA connector.

---

In general, there are a great many different [ways of connecting a display to a computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_connectors) and you'll need your computer and display (TV, monitor, projector etc) to match. For some combinations you can purchase a convertor but these are often problematic. In some cases you'll be able to buy a video adapter that fits in your computer's internal expansion sockets and which has an output connector that matches something your TV has as an input connector.